# MVC Upload csv file to database, but select which columns to be inserted

Tags: c#, sql, razor, model-view-controller, datatable

Need some help with uploading data from csv files to a database. The database has (of course) pre-specified column names, and I want to enable the user to choose which columns in the CSV files go to which columns in the database.

View code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="FileUpload" style="margin-left:40px;cursor:pointer;" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" style="margin-left:40px;cursor:pointer;" id="upload" value="Upload" />
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload)
    {
        // Set up DataTable place holder
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload.FileName);
string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
FileUpload.SaveAs(path);
dt = ProcessCSV(path);

return view(dt);}

private static DataTable ProcessCSV(string fileName)
    {
        //Set up our variables
        string Feedback = string.Empty;
        string line = string.Empty;
        string[] strArray;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow row;

        // work out where we should split on comma, but not in a sentence
        Regex r = new Regex(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))");

        //Set the filename in to our stream
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);

        //Read the first line and split the string at , with our regular expression in to an array
        line = sr.ReadLine();
        strArray = r.Split(line);

        //For each item in the new split array, dynamically builds our Data columns. Save us having to worry about it.
        Array.ForEach(strArray, s => dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn()));

        //Read each line in the CVS file until it’s empty
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            row = dt.NewRow();

            //add our current value to our data row
            row.ItemArray = r.Split(line);
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        //Tidy Streameader up
        sr.Dispose();

        //return a the new DataTable
        return dt;

    }
```

So I have managed to upload the file to the server, read the data from csv file into a datatable. Now I just need to return the datatable columns with a list of the column names in the database to the user, who can then select which column should go in.

I now need a view that will display the column names in a new form. This is where I really need help, not sure how to pass the column names from the imported CSV back to the view, for then to pass the selected column names back to the controller.

```
    @model System.Data.DataTable
@using System.Data;

<h2>Columns to include</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column name</th>
            <th>Select database column name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @col.ColumnName
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>

        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am hoping to use something like this in the end

```
                    SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping ColFirstName = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("Column1", "Firstname");
                SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping ColLastName = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("Column2", "Surname");
                SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping ColDOB = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("Column3", "Dateofbirth");

                copy.ColumnMappings.Add(ColFirstName);
                copy.ColumnMappings.Add(ColLastName);
                copy.ColumnMappings.Add(ColDOB);
```

Comment: Are you having some trouble with this code?

Comment: I am looking for additional code that will return the column names to the user, and allow them to select which columns to be inserted into the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ColumsViewModel
{
    public string[] SelectedNames { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Names { get; set; }
}
```

Extend your public ActionResult UploadFile

```
var model = new SearchViewModel();

        var names = dt.Columns.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.ColumnName,
            Text = x.ColumnName
        }).ToList();

 model.Names = names;
 return View(model);
```

Replace your @foreach in your view:

```
@model namespace.ViewModels.ColumsViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("SelectedColumns", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
     @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedNames, Model.Names, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "size", "15" } })
}
```

Use CTRL+Mouse click to select multiple values.

Create action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SelectedColumns(ColumsViewModel model)
    {
          //you will have your selected columns in model.SelectedNames
          //now you can do what you need with them
    }
```

It is possible to have some misspelling because i not actual test it with VS so you can fix it. The important is to catch the idea.